# Problem with the function update() using Repository pattern to write REST API

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I have a problem that all the create-read-delete using Repository Pattern is good but the update function is error. I still have the data but the information is not updated.

This is my code in EventController

```
public function update(EventRequest $request, $id)
{

        $events = $this->repository->update($request->all());

       return $this->sendResponse($events->toArray(), 'Successfully updated the Event!!');
    }
```

This is i use DI for inject from the Repository, this is EventRepository.php

```
public function update($id, array $array) {

        $events = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
        $events->update($array);
        return $events;
    }
```

when i use dd($array) and the result returns [] without anything. Can anyone help me. Did i write anything wrong in this. Or i write the wrong Request

```
public function rules()
    {
        // $id = $this->events ? ',' . $this->events->id : '';

        return $rules = [

        'event_title' => 'required|max:255',
        'event_type_id' => 'required|integer|between:1,3',
        'from_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        'to_date' => 'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|nullable',
        'is_recurring' => 'boolean|required',
        'remarks' => 'nullable',
         ]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method takes two arguments:

```
public function update($id, array $array) {
```

However, that's not how you are calling it:

```
$this->repository->update($request->all());
```

I take it `$request->all()` gives you an array, so pass the ID first.

```
$this->repository->update($id, $request->all());
```

Comment: i still get the problem 

Too few arguments to function App\\Repositories\\EventsRepository::update(), 1 passed in C:\\Users\\Snowfox1991\\Desktop\\Capstone project\\back-end\\back-end\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Events\\EventsController.php on line 99 and exactly 2 expected"

And this is line 99

$events = $this->repository->update($id, $request->all());

Comment: It is appeared to be another error Call to a member function toArray() on boolean. Maybe the logic of code is wrong.